# how to implement the (Done) button in android with flutter

Tags: flutter, search, textfield

i want to implement searching api when the textField changed, now it is work either any problems, but i should press (DONE) button in my android mobile keyboard, i need to do what (done) button does wither in (onCahnged) or in any other button, thank you...

this is my code:
this is when i call api with search word, which is in textField, and it is work without problems:

```
TextEditingController search = TextEditingController();

  searchCat() async {
    var res = await http.get(Config.url+"cat/"+search.text);
    if(res.statusCode == 200){
      var jsonObject = json.decode(res.body);
      return jsonObject['result'];
    }
  }
```

and here is my TextField:

```
 child: TextField(
                  controller: search,
                  onChanged: (txt){
                        searchCat();
                  },
                  autofocus: false,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    hintText: 'Searching',
                    contentPadding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14.0, bottom: 5.0, top: 5.0),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
```

and this code to display data, as i said, it work perfect but just when i press (Done) button in keyboard

```
Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: searchCat(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(snapshot.data != null){
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return CatTile(
                    cid: snapshot.data[index]['id'],
                    img:snapshot.data[index]['img'],
                    name: snapshot.data[index]['name'],
                    desc: snapshot.data[index]['desc'],
                  );
                },
              );
            }else{
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            }
          },
```

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Done button do? I think it makes TextField unfocused => thus we can play around with `FocusNode` class.

Please check https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus

Comment: i found the solution in this part>>>>>
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus#3-give-focus-to-the-textfield-when-a-button-is-tapped